# Get extents of map view?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

Does anyone know of an easy way to get the extents of the view in a MapFragment or SupportMapFragment?

That is, I need to get GPS coordinates for the top-left and bottom-right corners of the viewable area for a Google Play Services MapFragment as displayed below:[image: MapFragment view]

I need to be able to get these coordinates when the user resizes or relocates the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().farLeft
```

Read more about [`VisibleRegion`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion.html).

Comment: getVisibleRegion() was helpful... not sure about .farLeft.  I ended up using .latLngBounds instead which gave me the opposite corners of what I thought I wanted, but it was what I needed.